# Change default text (-Any-) of select option in Exposed View Filter

Tags: views

I am using views exposed filter.

[image]

I want to change the text `-Any-` into something else.
How can I do that (without using jquery/javascript) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for this. If anyone is looking for the solution can look into this example.

```
 function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

     //Got the Form Id by using inspect element/Firebug
     if($form["#id"] == 'views-exposed-form-tutors-page'){

         //field_city_tid is the Filter Identifier Key
         $form['field_city_tid']['#options']["All"] = 'Desired Text';

     }


  }
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the view should be tested:

    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'my_view_name' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'my_view_display_name') {
      // your code
      }
    }

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module you can do this using the views interface. Changed exposed form style to   'better exposed filters' and adjust the settings

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single- or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively. Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed filters to make for a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks @David Coote. Found an easy solution for now. Will look into this module too to check out the options it provides.

Comment: Can you please explain how one can do that, David? I don't see this option when I install BEF into Drupal 8. Thanks.

Comment: For Drupal 10, in the Better Exposed Filter settings, under "Exposed Filter Settings" and under the specified filter (Exposed filter "<filter name here>") there is an "Advanced Filter Options" expandable details element with a field labeled "Rewrite the text displayed". In that field put the text "- Any -|- Select-" on a single line and it will changed the default "- Any -" to "- Select".

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this goal via implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Let e.g.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

        if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'test' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'page_1') {
           // do your alteration stuff
 $form['field_city_tid']['#empty_option'] = t('All');// Or whatever you want to do
        }
        if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'test' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'page_2') {
           // do your alteration stuff 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Concrete example of an exposed Boolean filter for a view on a *custom entity*. Note that I had to add `_value` to field names.

- Custom module name: `rsc`
- View machine name: `transactions`
- Page machine name: `purchase`
- Field name: `field_order_shipped`

Actual code:

```
function rsc_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
{
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-transactions-purchase') {
    $form['field_order_shipped_value']['#options']['All'] = 'Any';
    $form['field_order_shipped_value']['#options']['1'] = 'Yes';
    $form['field_order_shipped_value']['#options']['0'] = 'No';
  }
}
```